# Security system activates intermittently on 2007 Montego

Tags: security, alarm, intermittent-problems

This is a 2007 Mercury Montego.

The car starts but at any time the security light (padlock) comes on and either stalls engine or makes it hesitate, then it will restart or keep running after hesitation.

I've replaced batteries in both key fobs. The locksmith says it's not a key issue since it starts the engine.

Could the PATS be failing?